# Remapping mouse buttons to single-button hotkeys not usable on the keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse, autohotkey, hotkeys

I have a Roccat Kone AIMO and I want to remap the buttons to buttons that are not on my keyboard, like the <kbd>F13</kbd>-<kbd>F24</kbd> keys. I could theoretically do this via the "assign a hotkey" function in Roccat Swarm, but for that I need to be able to press the key.

### Why would you want to do that?

I like to play Minecraft, but I prefer to play it using my mouse (I know, I'm crazy). To do this I need to set my controls to keyboard or mouse functions. I still want to take full advantage of my keyboard so that I can have hotkeys on my keyboard for things like mods, recording software, soundboards, etc. This means I need to remap my mouse buttons to keys that are not on the keyboard (like <kbd>F13</kbd>-<kbd>F24</kbd>).

### But you can just use AutoHotkey for that!

Yes, I know. You could, through running scripts by pressing the mouse button. But only if you are going to do things that don't require holding down a mouse button. Roccat Swarm does not register programmed keystrokes like those from AutoHotkey when setting a hotkey for your mouse buttons. This means that the only way to set a hotkey is to actually physically press it, and I don't want to spend a whole lot of money on a fancy mechanical keyboard.

### So, my question:

How can I "press" keys so that I can set my mouse to keys that I can't press on my keyboard? These could be the <kbd>F13</kbd>-<kbd>F24</kbd> keys, or even keys that require shift to access like ~!@#<>?": and all those other symbols.

### And the answer?

I don't think you can. You can definitely do instantaneous clicks, but no holding. Prove me wrong, please!